# LeetCode algorithm #257 Binary Tree Paths

Tags: python, binary-tree

For the LeetCode algorithm problem #257 Binary Tree Paths. I know we can use empty string  `path` to concate node values, but why do I also always get output like `[[1,2,5,3],[1,2,5,3]]` when i try to use list `path` to store node value?

code:

```py
class Solution:
    def binaryTreePaths(self, root):
        """
        :type root: TreeNode
        :rtype: List[str]
        """
        # dfs
        
        res = []
        def helper(node, path):
            
            if not node: return 
            
            #path+=str(node.val)
            path.append(node.val)

            # leaf node
            if not node.left and not node.right:
                res.append(path)
                #return

            #path += '->'  
            helper(node.left, path)
            helper(node.right, path)

        helper(root, [])
        return res
```

test case : `[1,2,3,null,5]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing through a reference to the same `path` list to both recursive calls, so appending in those calls (and each recursive call) will append to the same list.

Somewhat Related - ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument)

Strings are immutable. Mutating a string returns a *new reference*, thus why the solution may work using strings instead.